# DB Migration wizard MySQL workbench showing python pyodbc not installed error

Tags: mysql-workbench, pyodbc

I am trying to migrate a 1.4 TB DB on SQL server to MySQL. I am using MySQL workbench to do the migration

SQL server is 2022 dev edition. MySQL version is v 8

It is throwing following errors :-

> Could not connect to Source DBMS. ImportError("DLL load failed while
> importing pyodbc: The specified module could not be found."): error
> calling Python module function DbMssqlRE.connect

sometimes following error :-

> Could not import the pyodbc python module. You need pyodbc 2.1.8 or
> newer for migrations from RDBMSes other than MySQL.

- 

i have tried following to no avail

- manually installing the PyODBC using hte pip command  (pip install pyodbc)
- upgrading the ODBC drivers for SQL server to V 18
- installing lower version (8.0.20) of sql workbench and then migrating to higher version(8.0.34)

[image]

Comment: Ran into the same pyodbc issue with MySQL Workbench v8.0.34. Looks like a regression, given the verified bug in v8.0.34: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=113374. Tried several fixes like installing Python v2.7 and pyodbc. Downgrading to v8.0.33 eventually worked, though it's possible a combo of these steps and the reinstall did the trick. https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Comment: When I uninstalled v8.0.34 and installed v8.0.33, It helped my by installing v8.0.33 of everything but the Workbench for which it installed v8.0.34.
Python dependency bugs seem to be a never ending problem with Python